# What's the best we can do for a SparseMatrix implementation?

Tags: c++, matrix

I was using Eigen matrix framework, and the SparseVector library.  I was running into performance issues, and I all need from it is Sparse vector dot product.  So I rolled my own SparseMatrix implemenation, hoping it'd somehow be a bit faster:

A bit of sample code:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std ;

struct SparseMatrix
{
  map<int, Vector> vals ;

  Vector dot( SparseMatrix& o )
  {
    SparseMatrix *LS, *RS ;

    // iterate over the smaller of the 2 
    if( vals.size() < o.vals.size() )
    {
      // walk vals
      LS = this ;
      RS = &o ;
    }
    else
    {
      LS = &o ;
      RS = this ;
    }

    // walk LS
    Vector sum = 0 ;

    for( map<int,Vector>::iterator LSIter = LS->vals.begin() ; LSIter != LS->vals.end() ; ++LSIter )
    {
      const int& key = LSIter->first ;

      // use the key, see if RS has a similar entry.
      map<int,Vector>::iterator RSIter = RS->vals.find( key );
      if( RSIter != RS->vals.end() )
        sum += RSIter->second * LSIter->second ;
    }

    return sum ;
  }
} ;
```

So the dot product of 2 vectors, say that had entries like:

```
+---------------+
| vec 1         |
| index   value |
|   2      18   |
|   7       4   |
|  18      33   |
+---------------+

+---------------+
| vec 2         |
| index   value |
|   2       1   |
|  15      87   |
|  21      92   |
+---------------+
```

The dot product is then 18.

So, as you can see I used `std::map` to do element look up, to see if an element from one vector is in another vector.

Since I'm using integer indexing and 1d arrays only, is there a way I can make the lookup faster?  My sparse matrix multiply is still a bottleneck (performance of my code is only marginally faster than Eigen)

Comment: You could improve the first `if-else`  as : `SparseMatrix *LS=&o, *RS=this; if (vals.size() < o.vals.size()) std::swap(LS, RS);` which is short and simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a vector of pairs: index -> value, sorted by index.  Then iterate *both* vectors at once.  If you have the same index in two, multiply values, add this to result and go to the next pair in both vectors.  Else increment iteration index on the vector where the first element of pair is smaller.

Assuming you don't modify data a lot, of course.

I.e. in pseudocode:

```
for i = 0, j = 0; i < vec1.size && j < vec2.size:
    if vec1[i].first == vec2[j].first:
        result += vec1[i++].second * vec2[j++].second
    elif vec1[i].first < vec2[j].first:
        i++
    else
        j++
```

Comment: I agree with iterating two sorted sequences in parallel. If the data is often modified, it's going to get difficult, but for really sparse vectors (ie, assuming few elements) it should still be faster than having nodes allocated all over the memory (like a `list`) and the memory overhead of the nodes themselves that come with it.